# International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) dictionary guide in OS7

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I change the settings to display the in the dictionary the IPA pronunciation guide, rather than diacritical, guide in the iPhone 5S iOS 7?

Comment: was that possible on ios6?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way change the dictionary to IPA or download custom dictionaries to iOS (save for jailbreaking it). However...

This isn't a complete solution, but if you hit "Manage" and download "Oxford Dictionary of English" it *will* give you an English dictionary with IPA pronunciation. The only caveat is that it will be British English pronunciation.

Which depending on your use may or may not be useful since it will depend heavily on the particular word defined and your own dialect. For instance, the word "solution" in American English is usually pronounced something like *suh-loo-shun* while British English would pronounce it more like *sull-yoo-shun* (pardon my bad almost-diacritics), which can throw you off if you are using it to learn or reinforce already learnt IPA.